# how to check if a path which has length greater than PATH_MAX exists in C

Tags: c

I am exploring options in C, like how to find if a path name exists or not. I found few options like access function and through stat. But these throw an error name too long if the path length is greater than 1024. So I was thinking is there a way to find the path exists if its length is greater than 1024. I am trying to avoid doing "f open" because its somewhat costly with performance.

Comment: can you please post the code that you are using? the one with the limit of the path

Comment: Isn't it a quite safe guess there will be no path with a length greater than PATH_MAX?

Comment: @hetepeperfan saying "quite a safe guess" already makes it look like it's **not** a safe guess at all.